# Which algebraic structure captures the ordinal arithmetic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, definition, ordinals

Consider the <strike>set</strike> class $\mathrm{Ord}$ of all (finite and infinite) [ordinal numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number), equipped with [ordinal arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic) operations: addition, multiplication, and exponentiation. It is closed under these operations. Addition is non-commutative and there are no additive or multiplicative inverses.

> Is $(\mathrm{Ord}, +)$ a [magma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_%28algebra%29)? What [algebraic structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_structure) does $\mathrm{Ord}$ posses (under either/both $+, \times$ operations)?

Comment: It’s a proper class, not a set.

Comment: To add on Brian's comment, it is usually denoted by $\mathrm{Ord}$ or $\mathrm{On}$.

Answer (score 6):

With only addition, the ordinals form a [monoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid).

The ordinal numbers with both addition and multiplication form a non-commutative [semiring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring).

To quote from Wikipedia's page about [semirings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring#Further_generalizations):

> A near-ring does not require addition to be commutative, nor does it require right-distributivity. Just as cardinal numbers form a semiring, so do ordinal numbers form a near-ring.

(Although in the page of near-rings it is required that addition has inverse; so perhaps ordinals just form a **non-commutative semiring**).

Comment: Ordinal addition isn’t commutative; the addition in a semiring is required to be. And ordinal addition isn’t a group operation, but [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-ring), contrary to the statement that you quoted, requires a near ring to be a group under addition.

Comment: @Brian: I did mention this below the quote...

Comment: Didn’t see it. Did you by any chance do a really quick edit that didn’t show up as an edit? I could swear that I originally saw something slightly different.

Comment: @Brian: Yes. I did made a change or two. I didn't see your comment until much later though...

Comment: I may not have updated the page before making it. (And being on dial-up sometimes has slightly odd consequences.)

Answer (score 0):

In 1956 Tarski published a book titled [**Ordinal Algebras**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000X1NNW8) ([table of contents](https://www.sciencedirect.com/bookseries/studies-in-logic-and-the-foundations-of-mathematics/vol/19/suppl/C) and [review in *Journal of Symbolic Logic*](https://doi.org/10.2307/2964212) and [review in *Mathematical Gazette*](https://doi.org/10.2307/3610147) and [review, in German, in *Philosophische Rundschau*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/42570292)) that I think is relevant to what you're asking. I've paged through this book many times in university libraries (and I've also often paged through Tarski's 1949 book [**Cardinal Algebras**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0007DRPJY)—[Preface](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Extras/Tarski_cardinal/) and [review in *Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society*](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183514565) and [review in *Mathematical Gazette*](https://doi.org/10.2307/3611337) and [review in *Journal of Symbolic Logic*](https://doi.org/10.2307/2267069) and [review in *Science Progress*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43413694)), but I don't know very much about it. Maybe some of the set theory specialists in StackExchange can say more about these two books by Tarski.

Comment: I actually have **Cardinal Algabras**. I found it second hand for pennies. However it is related to the concept of **Jonsson Cardinals** which is not algebra in the modern sense of the word.